# Is there a way of restarting/resetting a graphics card without disabling the device or restarting the computer?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

(Found one [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/628800/restart-my-graphics-card-without-rebooting) - but this causes Windows 10 to hang).

I've been doing some machine learning and CUDA testing recently - Whenever I max my graphics card out for a while, I see a few random issues (slow framerates in various hardware accelerated apps) that gets quite annoying.

Rebooting works fine - but, when doing this workload, I have so many apps open, it again is quite annoying.

Going to Device Manager, right clicking disable, then enabling works - but, it causes my multi monitor configuration to be lost and I have to reposition everything.

Maybe my Cuda scripts aren't perfect or similar, but, I don't see why it is doing what it is doing when I am finished.

Is there any safe/quick/official way to restart the state or a driver of a graphics card whilst the system is running, without losing multiple desktop config?

Comment: @Topperfalkon Windows 10 includes built-in solutions for restarting the GPU. See my answer below.

Comment: @music2myear Existing answer to duplicate as the same key combination

Comment: Oh I see that. 4th answer down: https://superuser.com/a/1148091/74026

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 includes a default key combination that restarts the GPU and relevant subsystems:

<kbd>WIN</kbd> - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> - <kbd>B</kbd>

Articles mentioning this go back a year, so it should be available in at least build 1703.